# Wrong hql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;

@ManyToOne
private User ownerUser;

@ManyToMany
private Set<User> grantedUsers;
```

When I run following query:

```
select Item from Item d, d.grantedUsers u where ownerUser.id= :id or u.id =:id
```

I see error message:

```
[2014-07-21 15:07:31] d.grantedUsers is not mapped [select Item from com.test.Item d, d.grantedUsers u where ownerUser.id= :id or u.id =:id]
```

Entity is mapped in hibernate/spring `*.xml` file.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`select Item from Item d, d.grantedUsers u where ownerUser.id= :id or u.id =:id`

This whole query seems strange to me. My bet is that `Hibernate` tries to threat `d.grantedUsers` in `from` clause as entity class (whitch is not mapped). Try that:

`select d from Item d where ownerUser.id= :id or d.grantedUsers.id =:id`

Comment: `d.grantedUsers.id` would it work?? as its a set not an object

Comment: You need to use collection operation keywords for collections in HQL.

Comment: @Antoniossss any example please

Answer (score 0):

Specify the reverse relation and use mappedBy

Answer (score 0):

```
class User{
 ....

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="Item ")
 private Item item;
 ...

}

FROM User where id= :grantedUsersIds or id = :ownerUserids
```

You should have manytoOne relationship in your User class for Item and from above query you can get all your Item

Answer (score 0):

From the hibernate docs at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

```
select d from Item d join d.grantedUsers u 
    where d.ownerUser.id = :id or u.id = :id
```